# I have 300 blue marbles and 700 green marbles. What is the likelihood I pull more than 100 blue marbles given that I select 200 marbles?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have 700 green marbles and 300 blue marbles. I am going to pull 200 marbles and I want to know the probability that I get more than 100 blue marbles in my collection.

This is what I'm trying to calculate to solve the problem:

|possible ways to pull 100 or more blue marbles | 
/ |possible ways to pull 200 marbles|

I understand that this is a combinations without replacement problem. I'm not sure which formula that I want to use when I calculate the likelihood that someone pulls a blue marble.

Comment: Temporarily assume each marble has its own unique identifier like a barcode.  This helps us organize our thoughts.  If we pulled exactly $k$ blue marbles, pick which specific $k$ blue marbles those happened to be and which $200-k$ green marbles that happened to be pulled with it.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I calculate the likelihood of pulling a specific set of 100 blue marbles? Like Blue marble 1, 2 and so on?

Comment: Should this be $\dbinom{300}{100}$ / $\dbinom{1000}{200}$? My thinking is that this is how many ways I can pull 100 blue marbles over how many ways I can pull any set of marbles.

Comment: No.  I am suggesting you count the number of ways that you pulled any 100 blue marbles along with any 100 green marbles.  You can count this using binomial coefficients.  There are $300$ blue marbles and we want to *choose* $100$ of them, meanwhile there are $700$ green marbles and we want to *choose* $100$ of them.  Applying rule of product finishes the numerator.  Then we divide by the number of ways of selecting $200$ marbles of any mix.  The probability of getting **exactly** $100$ blue marbles is then $\dfrac{\binom{300}{100}\binom{700}{100}}{\binom{1000}{200}}$.  Now... account for more

Comment: It may be important to note that the chance of this is *really, really small*.

Comment: You could argue that the numbers are "large enough" that you might model this as selection with replacement rather than without and use a normal approximation instead to get a rough estimate on the probability.  I would have preferred much larger numbers, but it does well enough I suppose giving an estimate of around $10^{-9}$ compared to the true value which is closer to $10^{-11}$

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the probability of more than 100 blue marbles. I feel like I'd be better off doing this as a monte carlo simulation.

Comment: I get that the probability of 100 or more marbles is Pr(100 blue | 200 green) + Pr(101 blue | 199 green) + Pr(102 blue | 198 green) and so on. I just don't know how to calculate that.

Comment: @Cauder You can see the calculation [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28x%3D101%29%5E200+%28+300+choose+x%29*%28700++choose+%28200-x%29%29%2F%281000+choose+200+%29) The probability is practically zero. I don´t see why a monte carlo simulation would help here.

Comment: @Cauder Any reply?

Comment: That was very helpful. I found a simulation was the easiest for this problem and so I have a simulation running that assigns blue to marbles 1:300 and green to marble 301:1000, pulls 200 marbles and output 0 or 1 depending on whether it got 100 or more blue marbles and repeats 10,000 times.